# Can someone accept other user old question?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Can someone accept other user old question? Example:

If "A" have a question posted. Then "B" answered the question (and it is good and acceptable). But "A" didn't open his/her account for 1,5 years. Can someone (say it "C", high reputation user) accept this question cause it is acceptable answers?

I ask this because there is a lot of user aren't open his/her account and didn't accept the answer, even it is acceptable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't make (or force) people to accept an answer. What you can do instead is vote up the answer you think is best.

If everyone keeps doing that it just works out.

Comment: I think we should be allowed if the user explcitly states that the answer did indeed solve the problem, and the user has been inactive a while. It can work on the honor system, as it currently works now.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ I don't think so, because accepting answer isn't that important. The most important thing is upvoting good/helful answers. Sometimes (if not manytimes) accepted answer is not the best answer for a question, but a most upvoted answer is.