# Any circumstance to allow someone other than the question asker to select the answer to a question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Is there any circumstance where someone other than he who asked the question can select an answer? And if so, how/in what way would that answer selection be carried out?

I've seen a lot of posts that were abandoned by their original author, some popular, some with low votes; this is one that struck my curiosity:

[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Obviously the correct answer is a community wiki, and an answer selection here isn't *really* needed, but the original author's account no longer exists. Is there any possible way this question could have an answer selected, maybe in another question where there are many answers but only one really correct way?

Comment: Thats a good question, I think moving it to a whole new question would forfeit all those up-votes for the original posters, but maybe a mod could make this answer accepted since it is a community wiki.

Comment: Right, that is what I was thinking. My question is in general, though, are moderators the only ones allowed to have "pseudo-askubuntu-sudo powers" and accept an answer when it's not their question?

Comment: AFAIK There is no way for anyone to accept an answer apart from the OP, not even a mod, I know there is a question discussing this on here somewhere but I can't find it.

Comment: Found it, http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5289/can-someone-accept-other-user-old-question?rq=1 and a meta discussion http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178666/for-unanswered-questions-automatically-accept-an-answer-when-op-says-thanks

Comment: Thank you for the links @MarkKirby they are really enlightning.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I guess that answered my question @MarkKirby. It's a little surprising how bad the community received that suggestion.